# Writing a client-server application that uses ssl / tls using java without beeing able to use keytool

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

What I'm planning to do is writing a client-server application that uses a SSL (TLS) connection to exchange data.

As the client is downloadable and I can not guarantee access to the keystore I'm looking for a way to import certificates at runtime.

What I need:

- A way to import the server's **public** key/certificate into the client application
- A way to import the server's **private** key/certificate into the server application

What I found out so far:

```
// load the server's public crt (pem), exported from a https website
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(new
FileInputStream("C:\\certificate.crt"));

// load the pkcs12 key generated with openssl out of the server.crt and server.key (private) (if the private key is stored in the pkcs file, this is not a solution as I need to ship it with my application)
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\certificate.pkcs"), "password".toCharArray());
ks.setCertificateEntry("Alias", cert);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init(ks);

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, "password".toCharArray());

// create SSLContext to establish the secure connection
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

This does not work for me as I'm getting an error:

> java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported at ks.setCertificateEntry("Alias", cert);

Also, I think pkcs12 is used to store private keys which is not what I want.

I'm new to java and I'm really stuck with that problem now.

Thanks in advance,

Kazuo

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, this is not how SSL works. The peer public keys are exchanged in the protocol.

Comment: Well I just needed to add the server certificate to the client's trusted store. Without using keytool. And that is how it's done.
(See user384706's answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sun's implementation of `#PKCS12` does not allow to store trusted certificates if are not part of the chain of the private key.
If you **need** to use `#PKCS12` you have to switch to a different provider e.g. Bouncy Castle supports this.
If you do not have a requirement on keystore type you can switch to `JKS` which is java's keystore and allows to set trusted certificates (i.e. not part of the private key).
For `JKS` you can use the default provider i.e. SUN.
**UPDATE:**
So your code would have to change as follows:

```
//Create a temp keystore with the server certificate  

KeyStore ksTemp = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");    
ksTemp.load(null, null);//Initialize it  
ksTemp.setCertificateEntry("Alias", cert);   
ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
// save the temp keystore
ks.store(bOut, password);  

//Now create the keystore to be used by jsse   
Keystore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");   
store.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(bOut.toByteArray()), password);
```

Now you use the keystore `store` in your code which has the server's trusted certificate and not the private key.
From the comments in the code I noticed that you have a PKCS12 created using OpenSSL?
If you already have a p12 then you can not use "JKS" for KeyManager.
You will have to use `PKCS12` and load it as `PKCS12` to use it in the `kmf`.
So you will have to use 2 types in your app

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer!
I don't need to use PKCS12. I'm just looking for a way to establish a secure connection using the public cert with the client, and the private cert with the server.
How do I create a JKS cert? And how do I ensure that it contains the public/private key only?

Comment: You do not need a `JKS` cert.`JKS` is just a different format of `PKCS12` and is used to store `X509Certificates` or/and Private keys.Just change your code as I mention in the answer.You do not need anything else.Once you test it do not forget to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Changing the code gives me an "invalid keystore" error.

Could you provide me with a way to store a X509 cert (client) and another way to store the private key (server)?
I tried to pass "null" to the keystore.load function in order to create a new keystore just containing the certificate. It does not throw an error but does not load the x509 either.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The certificate is loaded properly now!
I think I'm going to create a new private key and certificate using keytool.
On the server side I just have to load the .jks keystore containing the private key that I created with keytool?

Comment: Keytool supports both JKS and PKCS12. You can use either one. Just make sure you load it properly (as JKS or PKCS12) in your server code.

Comment: Insecure answer to insecure question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a certificate at runtime. You don't need to download a keystore to the client. You just need your server certificate signed by a recognized CA.

What you are proposing is insecure. The client has to acquire the certificates to trust via a different means than the channel than the certificate is authenticating. Otherwise there is no reason to trust the certificate, or the channel, or the certificate, ... PKI with CA certs takes care of all that. Your proposal just undermines the scurity built into PKI and SSL. Don't do this.

Comment: You are right on what you say.But if you see the comments in the code he has the server's private key as well.It seems he owns both sides

Comment: Yes I do own both sides.
The certificates are both signed by an own CA.
I just ended up creating a client keystore containing the ca cert, server cert, the client cert and the client key and a server keystore containing the ca cert, client cert, server cert and server key. The client keystore ships with the client.

Comment: @Kazuo so ship the client *truststore* with the client too! Your online solution isn't secure.

Comment: @user384706 I don't see what difference that makes.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I'm loading that Java Key Store created for the client as the client's Trust Store. Otherwise it would not work. But it does.
All I need is an encrypted connection and it's working now.
What do you mean by saying that it isn't secure? What's the problem with that setup?
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Kazuo you have a connection between the client and the server. It is insecure until SSL authenticates it via the PKI certificates. So how can downloading a certificate over an insecure connection possibly make it secure?

Comment: Downloading a certificate over an insecure connection? I'm not planning to download the keystore at runtime or something. I will ship it with the client (either on a usb stick or via download from a https Webserver).

Comment: @Kazuo so why do you need a way to import certificates at runtime?

Comment: I don't. But I would need it if I was not able to ship a java keystore file with it. First I did not know that it is possible to create a jks containing all needed certificates and keys.

Comment: So what is your question?